# scanf reads a character in loop but does not compare properly with a conditional

Tags: loops, unix, while-loop, char, scanf

Im trying to scan in a character in a loop and if it does not equal a certain character it will continue to loop. It prints the character correctly but the conditional to exit does not work(it continues to try to scan). Heres my code:

```
do{
    scanf("%c",&user_input);
    printf("%c",user_input);
    }while(user_input =='w' ||'a'|| 's'|| 'd' || 'q');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take another look at the condition of your while-loop.  While it makes sense in English ("while this is that, or that, or that...") it's an improper use of the OR operator.  What's going on is that each of those characters you're checking for (besides the 'w') is interpreted as a Boolean expression.  Each of those characters is really a positive number, which in C is interpreted as True.  The condition is always true, so that's why your loop never terminates.

You'll need to compare each character to `user_input` in each part of the condition; e.g.

`while(user_input == 'w' || user_input == 'a' || user_input== 's' || ...`

Comment: Thank you, It's always so obvious once I actually see whats wrong.